# How to generate a range of random numbers with a specified step size?

Tags: r

Can anyone help me how to do this in R?

I know how to generate a list of random numbers, and also how to generate a sequence with a certain step size.

But I don't how to generate a range of random numbers, where I want the difference between consecutive numbers to be a fixed value (or, no bigger than, say 0.05).

Comment: If it were a fixed value distance, then only the first number can be random and all others are fixed (by adding or subtracting x +/- n*0.05)

Comment: If the difference is a fixed value then the number will no longer be ranodm

Answer (score 0):

```
start <- 0  
end <- 1  
step <- 0.1  
s <- seq(start, end, step) # 0, .1, .2, .3 , ...  
r <- runif(length(s)-1) # 'length(s)-1' is number of intervals in s 
r*step +s[-length(s)] # 'r*step' - shrinkage
```

is it OK for you ?

Answer (score 0):

try this function, `n` is the length of the sequence, `limit` changes the fixed value between consecutive numbers, set startpoint and startWidth to give generate a random start point number between `[ -startWidth, startWidth ]`

```
   generateSeq<-function(n,limit,startPoint=0,startWidth=1e+2){
      if(n<0){
        print("n must be an postive integer")
        break
      }
      if(as.integer(n)!=n){
        print("n must be an postive integer")
        break
      }
      r<-runif(1,startPoint-startWidth,startPoint+startWidth)
      for(ith in 1:n){
        r[ith+1]<-runif(1,r[ith]-limit,r[ith]+limit)
      }
      return(r)
    }
```

example:

```
generateSeq(5,0.05)
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate 10 random numbers between two arbitrary numbers (such as 1 and 12) which are exactly divisible by 0.05. The assumption is that the distance between consecutive numbers is varying by a random multiple of 0.05.

```
start = 1
end = 12
step = 0.05
round ( runif ( n=10, min=start, max=end ) * step ) / step
```

A repeatable example using set seed.

```
set.seed(seed = 12)
round(runif(10,min = 1,max=12)/0.05)*0.05 
 [1]  1.75 10.00 11.35  3.95  2.85
 [6]  1.35  2.95  8.05  1.25  1.10
```